# Is there a file upload function in salt stack to upload a jar to JFrog Artifactory?

Tags: artifactory, salt-stack

I am using saltstack state script to create a jar from BitBucket and upload the jar to Artifactory. When uploading to Artifactory I see an authorization error. I am not sure if this is the right approach to achieve the upload to Artifactory.

I tried using CURL to achieve upload. I need to provide `-u myUser:myPassword` along the CURL command for it to work. I cannot provide the credentials in my salt state scripts. I am looking for a better option to achieve the upload without using login credentials. How to upload artifacts to artifactory using saltstack?

```
curl -X PUT -T /tmp/Batch.jar http://artifactory/artifactory/Batch.jar
```

Error:
stdout:

```
              {
                \"errors\" : [ {
                  \"status\" : 401,
                  \"message\" : \"Unauthorized\"
                } ]
              }
```

Comment: I'm not sure: is this an artifactory question: how to authorize upload without credentials? or a saltstack question: how to submit 'securely' credentials in saltstack?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Artifactory documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API), the REST API supports these forms of authentication:

- Basic authentication using your username and password
- **[Simplest]** Basic authentication using your username and API Key.
- Using a dedicated header (`X-JFrog-Art-Api`) with your API Key.
- Using an access token instead of a password for basic authentication.
- **[Recommended]** Using an access token as a bearer token in an authorization header
  (`Authorization: Bearer`) with your access token.

You will have to choose one of the above.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this sort of thing a couple of times. The easiest solution is to write a small salt execution module to do this work. This way you can store the artifactory credentials as pillar data and use the normal python requests or salt http helpers to make the web requests.

Looks like salt stack provides a module for artifactory alread: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.artifactory.html

It may not do exactly what you're looking for, but you could definitely extend it: https://github.com/saltstack/salt/blob/develop/salt/modules/artifactory.py

The saltstack docs for writing execution modules can be here:
https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/